# TargetInvocationException @ PropertyInfo.GetValue(target, null) with Target Type MemoryStream

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I wanted to read all the public property values of objects and wrote following code:

```
private List<PropertyInfo> GetListOfProperties(object objectToRegister,
                                BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                            BindingFlags.Public)
{
    Type type = objectToRegister.GetType();
    List<PropertyInfo> curListOfProperties = new List<PropertyInfo>();
    curListOfProperties.AddRange(type.GetProperties()
                                    .Where((propertyInfo) =>
                                    !propertyInfo.GetIndexParameters().Any()));
    return curListOfProperties;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var objectToRegister = new MemoryStream();

// ... eventually write things into MemoryStream e.g. Image.Save(objectToRegister , "Bmp") 
// ... eventually do nothing with objectToRegister 

foreach (var propertyInfo in GetListOfProperties(objectToRegister))
{
    if (propertyInfo.CanRead)
    {
        // -->> TargetInvocationException
        value = propertyInfo.GetValue(objectToRegister , null); 
    }
}
```

The Exception looks like this

> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream.    at
>   System.IO.Stream.get_ReadTimeout()

Now I would like to exclude such unsupported Properties from the return value of `GetListOfProperties`

Comment: Why do you pass `declaringInstance` (and what is this?) to `propertyInfo.GetValue` (instead of `objectToRegister`?

Comment: @stakx `objectToRegister` is a `MemoryStream`. `GetValue` needs an instance of his class.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem related to your reflection code. What exactly are you doing with the `MemoryStream`? Add that code.

Comment: @Yuval: I can see what `objectToRegister` is; I was asking about `declaringInstance`.

Comment: @ stakx You're right,  `declaringInstance` was just a copy/paste fail. I changed it to `objectToRegister`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code by itself looks OK to me.

But I suspect that your approach has one fundamental design flaw: namely your assumption that you can read any property successfully, anytime, in any order.

Well-designed types might fulfill this assumption, but unfortunately there are types out there that follow different protocols:

- An object may have a property `HasValue`, which specifies whether another propery `Value` may be queried (or whether that would result in an `InvalidOperationException` or similar).

  (A better-designed type might have a `TryGetValue` method or a nullable `Value` property instead.)
- An object may have to be `Initialize`-d first before anything can be done with it.

etc. You came across another such example with `Stream.ReadTimeout`, which apparently simply isn't supported on `MemoryStream`.

If you have to get your reflection code to work with *any* type, here are some options:

1. The easiest way is to simply "ignore" any errors by wrapping the call to `propertyInfo.GetValue` in a `try`/`catch` block (and perhaps collect all caught exceptions into an `AggregateException`).
2. If you want to treat some specific types differently to work around particular issues (like your case with `MemoryStream`), you could create various implementations of your reflection code and choose a strategy based on an object's `Type`. Here's a very crude example to give you an idea:

   ```
   interface IPropertyInspector
   {
       PropertyInfo[] GetProperties(object obj);
   }

   class GenericPropertyInspector : IPropertyInspector { /* your current implementation */ }

   class StreamPropertyInspector : IPropertyInspector { /* does not return e.g. ReadTimeout if CanTimeout is false */ }

   Dictionary<Type, IPropertyInspector> inspectors = ...;
   inspectors[typeof(MemoryStream)] = new StreamPropertyInspector();

   ...
   Type t = objectToRegister.GetType();
   IPropertyInspector inspector;
   if (!inspectors.TryGetValue(t, out inspector))
   {
       inspector = new GenericPropertyInspector();
   }
   var properties = inspector.GetProperties(objectToRegister):
   // do something with properties
   ```

   Such an additional level of indirection would allow you to filter out properties that are known to cause problems.

Comment: Just to complete the answer, `Stream` class has properties called `CanRead`, `CanTimeout`, `CanSeek`, `CanWrite` which are used to indicate if you **can** call some other properties/methods. A better design would be some sort of `MayBe<T>` to be returned instead of throwing exceptions, but this is how it is (and will never change), so it's worth considering stakx advice.

Comment: At the moment  a `try/catch` block is my workaround. I have a problem with the fact that MemoryStream isn't the only type which passes through my code. However, the appearance of this useless exception will make it heavier to debug the code in future.

Comment: I hoped to find a property like `IsSupported` to sort out such propertyInfos, but as long as I can't find anything in this direction i'll accept this answer.

Comment: @Markus: There is no generic `IsSupported` for any property and any type. With `Stream`s in specific, the closest you can get is what Ivan mentioned in his comment above.